# How to load React GTM Module in Gatsby project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to use `react-gtm-module` in my Gatsby project, I used the library `@loadable/component` to load this module in my component. So, when I run `gatsby develop`, I get the error `TagManager.initialize is not a function`

This is the code:

```
import loadable from '@loadable/component';

const TagManager = loadable(() => import('react-gtm-module'));

export const setupGtm = () => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    TagManager.initialize({
      gtmId: 'GTM-ID',
    });
  }
};
```

I would really like to use the `react-gtm-module` because I already have several codes already pre-configured, does anyone know how to use no gatsby?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have the GTM module configured in your `gatsby-config.js`?

Answer (score 1):

For this to run properly, you have to install the Gatsby plugin called `Google Tagmanager` inside your gatsby project, you can do that. by running

`npm install gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager`

When you are done, you have to get the plugin set up in your `gatsby-config.js` or `gatsby-config.ts` file.

Check out [this doc](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager/) from Gatsby for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I try with this plugin and now I get the error: gtag is not defined

Comment: The gtag definition will happen in your `gatsby-config.js` file, how did you configure it in there? Or did you?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the React-based dependency. It's far way easy to use the native Gatsby plugins for that since they will insert the script in the needed places automatically. I would suggest get riding off that snippet and using [`gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager/):

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager",
    options: {
      id: "YOUR_GOOGLE_TAGMANAGER_ID",

      // Include GTM in development.
      //
      // Defaults to false meaning GTM will only be loaded in production.
      includeInDevelopment: false,

      // datalayer to be set before GTM is loaded
      // should be an object or a function that is executed in the browser
      //
      // Defaults to null
      defaultDataLayer: { platform: "gatsby" },

      // Specify optional GTM environment details.
      gtmAuth: "YOUR_GOOGLE_TAGMANAGER_ENVIRONMENT_AUTH_STRING",
      gtmPreview: "YOUR_GOOGLE_TAGMANAGER_ENVIRONMENT_PREVIEW_NAME",
      dataLayerName: "YOUR_DATA_LAYER_NAME",

      // Name of the event that is triggered
      // on every Gatsby route change.
      //
      // Defaults to gatsby-route-change
      routeChangeEventName: "YOUR_ROUTE_CHANGE_EVENT_NAME",
      // Defaults to false
      enableWebVitalsTracking: true,
    },
  },
]
```

You can omit the options you won't use.